# Does Anyone knows a NAT/PT free software?

Tags: ipv6

I was wondering if someone knows a NAT64 software, preferably for windows.

This is because i need to communicate a only IPv6 service with a only IPv4 network without going to the Internet. The service cannot have IPv4 and on the network IPv6 cannot be implemented. That's why I need a translator, a NAT64 / DNS64.

Forefront UAG from Microsoft has a NAT64, it works for me. But i want to know if some of you know a free alternative.

Thank you.

Comment: Teredo (built into Windows) doesn't do what you need?

Comment: Not. Teredo is a transition technologie for get a public IPv6 address when you are behind a NAT Device. This is not what I need in this case. I need a software that I put on a computer in the middle of a IPv4 network and IPv6 network and it translates. Thank you Brian.

Comment: @Steve I'm telling my problem. "I need to communicate a only IPv6 service with a only IPv4 network. The service cannot have IPv4 and on the network IPv6 cannot be implemented. That's why I need a translator, a NAT64 / DNS64.". For being exactly i would like to implement Microsoft Direct Access in a network with not IPv6 capabilities, not even ISATAP. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I only know of Linux or BSD based implementations. This is one with source and pre-built binaries for different Linux distributions: http://ecdysis.viagenie.ca/download.html

It also offers a live CD, so maybe it's a solution for you if you run it in VirtualBox or VMware.

Answer (score 1):

Let's list out some options and try to get your feedback for each.

**1)  Teredo.**

Provides connectivity to IPv6 hosts to IPv4 hosts.  Built into Windows and hence very easy to deploy.

**2)  IPv6 SOCKS proxy**

Sit the proxy on the IPv6 Internet and have one side sitting on your IPv4 intranet.

**3)  IPv6 HTTP proxy**

You do not specify which protocols you require, if it is only HTTP then a HTTP proxy would be a valid solution.

**4)  SSH tunnel**

You can implement an IPv6 SOCKS proxy simply with say PuTTY and a regular SSH server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know about the transitions technologies that you mention but none of them works for my everyroment. I'm looking for a NAT64 software.

Comment: @Ricardo you still haven't answered why?  I can only read between the lines and guess you have an IPv4-only application that you are trying to force into communicating with IPv6-only hosts.

Comment: I'm waiting for someone to knows a NAT64 implementation for Windows different to Microsoft UAG. If not my solution will be the one from Sander Steffan.

Yes It's something like that but just the opossitive way. I have an only IPv6 application (Microsoft Direct Access) and i need it to communicate with an IPv4 network by an ethernet cable. 
The problems is that for some concerns of the IT area they cannot make the network IPv6 capable. 
I need to put something in the middle what makes the translations, even in the DNS queries. That is what NAT64/DNS64 does. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to http://www.sixxs.net you can sign up for their IPv6 tunneling service which allows you to use [AICCU](http://www.sixxs.net/tools/aiccu/) to get a routable IPv6 address even if you're behind an IPv4 NAT.

This will let you access IPv6-only services from anywhere.

Comment: Hello @MikeyB. Thanks for your answer. That it's not what I'm looking for. For that I have as example Teredo or the tunnel service that you mention. But it's not what I need. I need to communicate as example, two LANS, one which only can have IPv4 and one which only can have IPv6 and without going to the Internet. That's why I need use the protocol NAT64.

Comment: @Ricardo, aha new information, add that to the question:  "without going to the Internet".

Comment: @Steve Doing that. :)

Comment: Then set up a proxy server (Squid) that has access to both networks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question confuses me a bit, because you mention a IPv6-only service to be reached from IPv4-only clients, and then call it NAT64. But looking up [NAT64 on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT64) gives me the answer I expect: NAT64 is for IPv6-only clients to reach IPv4-only services.

The 'easy' answer I can think of for your question is setting up a dual-stack device on your network which translates a dedicated v4 address to the v6 destination and advertising the v4 address on your v4-only network for the service. I am not aware of a Windows approach to this (a windows server version may be able to do this). Linux/BSD can be configured to do this.

Comment: Windows have native IPv6/IPv4 dual stack. But that is not what I need. 

For be clear I need to connect a Microsoft Direct Access Server (IPv6 only service) with a Network that only supports IPv4 and cannot install dual stack on that network.  In the Microsoft world what a i need is a UAG Server, it has NAT64/DNS64. I put it in the middle of the server and the network and everything works. I was wondering if somenone knows a free alternative.